# Rails sample_app sign-in page fails when accessed from Heroku

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm learning rails. I on [chapter 7](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-deploying_to_production_with_ssl_) of Michael Hartl's rails tutorial. I am trying to make a signup page where users can create an account. I can create users without problems when I run my app from a local environment (`localhost:3000`), however when I push the changes up to Heroku, pressing the sign-up button results in the error "We're sorry but something went wrong".

Checking the heroku logs I find:

```
Started GET "/signup" for [an ip address...] at 2012-08-27 21:36:15 +0000

Processing by UsersController#new as HTML

ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial /shared/error_messages with 
{:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:

* "/app/app/views"

Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (38.9ms)

6:     <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 137ms

5:   <div class="span6 offset3">
):

4: <div class="row">
app/views/users/new.html.erb:6:in     
  `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___3412900076253353202_33302880'

7:       <%= render '/shared/error_messages' %>

8:       <%= f.label :name %>
app/views/users/new.html.erb:7:in `block in 
  _app_views_users_new_html_erb___3412900076253353202_33302880'

9:       <%= f.text_field :name %>
```

Now I've run:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

and I've included `'pg', '0.12.2'` in my gemfile.

I've also rolled back the heroku db using:

```
$ heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE
```

and then re-migrated it

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

to no avail. Any ideas? It is strange because everything other aspect of the webpage works, and the whole thing works in my local environment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a partial:

```
Missing partial /shared/error_messages with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]
```

Check if it has been added to git.

Answer (score 1):

Krule correctly identified the problem. I had named the directory sample_app/app/views/Shared, when it should be sample_app/app/views/shared.

it is worth noting that changed the case of a directory in git is a little challenging because git isn't case sensitive. I had to execute these commands

> $ git mv Shared shared2
>
> $ git mv shared2 shared
>
> $ git commit -m "your message here"
>
> $ git add -A
>
> $ git push

then pushed to heroku:

> $ git push heroku
>
> $ heroku open

Thanks for the quick and accurate response!

Comment: It's worth noting that git is as sensitive to cases as much as File System you are using it on. So, if you are using NTFS or FAT (Windows) it's case insensitive, HFS+ (OS X) is usually case insensitive but case preserving...